# Circular hole in a <div>

Tags: html, css, mask, clip

I am looking for a way to create a square div of relative size, say, 70% x 70% with a background color and a circular hole in it (so that the background can be seen behind it) of the same size so that the sides of the div are tangent.

Comment: a png with a transparent hole in the middle as background on the div would probably work.

Comment: Show an image example of how you'd like it to look.

Comment: @MarcB’s suggestion wins for simplicity but a PNG won’t scale well. You could use an SVG with a hole in the middle instead.

Comment: @MarcB: Or an SVG so that it could scale with the `<div>` without visual artifacts.

Comment: yeah, svg would be better, but OP did basically suggest "simple answer".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `radial-gradient` to achieve this.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/600/400) 100% 100%;
}
div {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle, transparent 10%, #000 10%);
  background: -moz-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle, transparent 10%, #000 10%);
  background: radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle, transparent 10%, #000 10%);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

Here's an `svg` approach.

```css
body {
  background: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/600/400/);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 400 200" width="400" height="200">
  <path d="M0,0 L400,0 L400,200 L0,200z M200,100 m-50,0 a50,50 0 1,0 100,0 a50,50 0 1,0 -100,0z" fill="black" />
</svg>
```

Comment: There are browsers which aren't gecko nor webkit browsers. Please inlude the standard syntax without vendor prefix for them. Moreover, latest versions of major browsers don't require any prefix.

Comment: groovy looks great. real simple. I am getting a lot of jagged edges on the circle. Is there any way to fix this? thanks

Comment: @user2444319 - You could change it to `(50% 50%, circle, transparent 10%, #000 11%)` to smoothen the edges but Chrome still makes it look ugly. I'll add an alternate solution using `svg` to fix this issue.

Comment: thanks im looking forward to it

Comment: I would suggest you add your svg approach in the original question as well as it isn't present there.

Comment: is it possible to have a rectangle or triangle instead of circle inside?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py thanks for the answer but could you be more precise, which one is d attribute?

Comment: @johannesMatevosyan - d attribute of the path element enclosed in svg tags. I'm sorry I'm on my phone right now, can't edit the code for you.

Comment: @johannesMatevosyan - Anyway, here's the `d` attribute for rectangle - `"M0,0 L400,0 L400,200 L0,200z M200,100 m-50,0 v-25 h100 v50 h-100z"` and for triangle - `"M0,0 L400,0 L400,200 L0,200z M200,100 m0,-50 l35,100 h-70z"`

Comment: the value of the standard un-prefixed `radial-gradient` marked as invalid in my latest Opera (chrome) inspector.