# How can I create a create a hole within a DIV?

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas

So say I have the following HTML structure:

```
<canvas></canvas>
<div class="overLay">
    <button>Click me!</button>
</div>
```

The canvas is absolutely positioned with a negative z index, so the overlay is positioned over it (I have that much working). The issue is that I want the overlay div to have a white background, but the button to have a transparent background and show through to the canvas/body background color.

```
background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

doesn't work because it just shows the white background behind it. Any ideas on how to accomplish this effect?

The question this may have been marked as a potential duplicate of fails to account for the fact that buttons can have properties such as border-radius and offers no suitable solutions.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: show the css for the div and button...

Comment: So you essentially want your `<button>` to create a 'window' in your `.overLay`?

Comment: If I understand correctly this can't be done... you aren't looking for a transparent background, you are looking to make a "hole" in the parent

Comment: Correct, I want a hole through the parent

Comment: Since this question is on hold, I have posted a new answer to the question linked as duplicate. I think that it solves your question better than other options; the only problem is that it isn't supported in IE

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to create a hole inside an HTML element. A Transparent background can only be applied to an element that does not descend from a parent that has a non-transparent background.

What you could do, thought it's a little bit more complicate, is to create divs around your button, at it's same level, as siblings. Give those divs a white background, and then your transparent button should work.

I've created a sample using a table layout, where the button remains in the middle row, in the center cell. See that the button reveals the canvas background color:

```css
canvas {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: purple;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

.overLay {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: table;
}

.overLay button {
    background-color: Transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.overLay > div {
    display: table-row;
}

.overLay > .middle {
    height: 1px;
}

.overLay > div > div {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}

.overLay > .middle > div:nth-child(2) {
    width: 1px;
}

/* Now, set the background on the divs around the button */
.top, .left, .right, .bottom {
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<div class="overLay">
    <div class="top">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="middle">
        <div class="left"></div>
        <div>
            <button>Click me!</button>
        </div>
        <div class="right"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This almost works, but the issue is that it breaks things like border-radius

Answer (score 0):

Since in my original answer, you pointed the intention of using a border radius. So there's another approach to make this possible.

Based on [**this asnwer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27574572/circular-hole-in-a-div)

Make the overlay with a gradient radius background, that creates the gradient color center in the position where you want the button to be, at the button's size. Make the outer color as `white`, and the inner color as `Transparent;`.

Then, set your button's position. (I did this by centering it in a table layout):

```css
canvas {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background: purple;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

.overLay {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: table;
    background-color: white;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle, transparent 25px, white 0px);
    background: radial-gradient(50% 50%, circle, transparent 25px, white 0px);
}

.overLay > div {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

button {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<div class="overLay">
    <div>
        <button>Click me!</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm away from my computer at the moment, but will this work with a non circular button (just rounded corners, straight sides)? I've not used radial gradients before. If it is, don't worry about another example, I can find out how to do it, just wondering. This does look to be what I'm looking for though.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this approach would work only for a circle.... More than that, your best shot is to create a white, transparent holed, png background for the overlay, and place the button exactly over the spot...

Comment: A similar, but better technique, is to use box-shadow. There is an answer in the original question (the one marked as dup) using this technique, and it can handle any border-radius setting

Answer (score 0):

Mmm..., have you thought about using an SVG element with a mask. That should do the trick. Take a look at the snippet.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.your-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
button {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="your-canvas">
  <img width="512" alt="Weingarten Kuppel 8" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dd/Weingarten_Kuppel_8.jpg/512px-Weingarten_Kuppel_8.jpg"/>
</div>
<svg height="324" width="512">
  <defs>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rect width="512" height="324" fill="white"/>
      <rect x="181" y="112" width="150" height="100" fill="black"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <rect width="512" height="324" style="fill:rgba(255,0,0,.6);" mask="url(#mask)"/>
  <foreignObject class="node" x="181" y="112" width="150" height="100">
    <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <button>Click Me</button>
    </body>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

As far as i know it is even possible to use masking in pure css, but haven't had the time to look it up. Here is some information on using masks with svg [Clipping and masking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking).

Have fun.

Comment: This would be perfect, but I need the button to be in a div. Not a bad idea though

Answer (score 0):

**You could...**

- Reduce a canvas element to button size (== a button-canvas!),
- Use CSS to position the button-canvas as desired **over the div**,
- Add a click event listener on the canvas,
- Draw whatever design you need on the button-canvas.

This way you have complete flexibility using the amazing drawing tools available with the canvas element.

**Here's example code and a (fanciful) Demo.**

While this demo is just for fun, you can easily restyle this example & turn it into a reusable widget:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var width=80;
var height=40;
var borderwidth=4;
var x=0;
var y=0;
x+=borderwidth;
y+=borderwidth/2;
var w=width-borderwidth-borderwidth;
var h=height-borderwidth;
var depth=5;
//
var stopCount=8;
var angle=0;
var angleDelta=360;
//
var labelColor='black';

canvas.width=width;
canvas.height=height;

requestAnimationFrame(animate);

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
$("#canvas").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});


function makeGradient(){
  var g=ctx.createLinearGradient(0,0,cw,0);
  for(var i=0;i<stopCount;i++){
    var stop=i/stopCount;
    var hslDegrees=(angle+angleDelta*stop)%360;
    var hsl="hsl(" + hslDegrees + ",100%, 50%)"
    g.addColorStop(stop,hsl);
  }
  return(g);
}

function animate(){
  ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
  gradientBorder();
  ctx.font='12px verdana';
  ctx.fillStyle=labelColor;
  ctx.fillText('Click Me',x+10,y+25);
  angle++;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

//
function gradientBorder(){
  var lw=ctx.lineWidth
  var ss=ctx.strokeStyle;
  ctx.lineWidth=borderwidth;
  ctx.strokeStyle=makeGradient();
  //
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x+w-depth,y);
  ctx.lineTo(x+depth,y);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(  x-depth/2,y+h*1/6,  x+depth*2,y+h*2/6, x,y+h/2);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(  x+depth*2,y+h*4/6,  x-depth/2,y+h*5/6, x+depth,y+h);
  ctx.lineTo(x+w-depth,y+h);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(  x+w+depth/2,y+h*5/6, x+w-depth*2,y+h*4/6, x+w,y+h/2);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(  x+w-depth*2,y+h*2/6, x+w+depth/2,y+h*1/6, x+w-depth,y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.stroke();
  //
  var b2=borderwidth/2;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(x+w-depth-1,y+b2);
  ctx.lineTo(x+depth+2,y+b2);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(  x-depth/2+b2+2,y+h*1/6+1,  x+depth*2+b2,y+h*2/6, x+b2+1,y+h/2);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(  x+depth*2+b2,y+h*4/6+1,  x-depth/2+b2+1,y+h*5/6, x+depth+b2-2,y+h-b2);
  ctx.strokeStyle='#666';
  ctx.lineWidth=0.50;

  ctx.moveTo(x+depth+b2-2,y+h-b2);
  ctx.lineTo(x+w-depth-2,y+h-b2);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(  x+w+depth/2-b2-2,y+h*5/6, x+w-depth*2-b2+1,y+h*4/6, x+w-b2-2,y+h/2);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(  x+w-depth*2-b2+1,y+h*2/6, x+w+depth/2-b2-2,y+h*1/6, x+w-depth-b2+3,y+b2);
  ctx.strokeStyle='#666';
  ctx.lineWidth=0.50;
  ctx.stroke();
  //
  ctx.strokeStyle=ss;
  ctx.lineWidth=lw;

  ctx.fillStyle='gainsboro';
  ctx.fill();
}

function handleMouseDown(e){ labelColor='red'; }

function handleMouseUp(e){ labelColor='black'; }
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
.demo{
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  border:1px solid red;
  position:relative;
}
#canvas{
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;
  top:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='demo'>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</div>
```